# Python libvlc dynamic playlists

Tags: python, libvlc

I'm trying to convert a 1950s jukebox to play mp3 tracks in my man cave, so I'd drop a coin and select 2 tracks and they get added to my playlist and my Raspberry Pi starts playing the tracks. I'd choose more tracks and they would get added whist its still playing.

I've got the basic code working but after 3 weeks I still can't get libvlc to play tracks once the playlist has ended, I know it something to do with loading the medialist but I just can't solve it.

I have a GPIO input which adds a new track to the playlist, it appears to be adding it but they never play.

I've tried many ways and this week playing with a class I found to get it working - all fail, there just isn't much sample code out there that looks at modifying playlists on the fly, they all seem to work on directories which won't work for a jukebox where a user selects random tracks.

All I'm after is the ability to add tracks to the playlist whilst its playing and those tracks are added to the playlist as it's running.

```
class AudioPlayer:

def __init__(self):
    self.instance = vlc.Instance()
    self.mediaplayer = self.instance.media_player_new()
    self.mediaplayer.audio_set_volume(25)
    self.event_manager = self.mediaplayer.event_manager()
    self.event_manager.event_attach(vlc.EventType.MediaPlayerEndReached, self.trackEnded)
    self.event_manager.event_attach(vlc.EventType.MediaPlayerMediaChanged, self.changed_track)
    self.titleNum = 0
    self.playlist = []
    print ("Player Created")

def add_to_playlist(self, newtrack):
    self.playlist.append(newtrack)

def loadTrack(self, path):
    return self.instance.media_new(path)
    print("track loaded")

def playTrack(self, track):
    self.mediaplayer.set_media(track)
    print("PLAYING TRACK")
    self.mediaplayer.play()

def playCurrTrack(self):
    print("trying to load new track...")
    track = self.loadTrack(self.playlist[self.titleNum])
    print("trying to play track...")
    self.playTrack(track)

def trackEnded(self, event):
    print("Track ended")
    self.nextTrack()

def changed_track(self, event):
    print("Track Changed")

def prevTrack(self):
    self.setTitle(self.getTitle()-1)
    self.playCurrTrack()

def nextTrack(self):
    self.setTitle(self.getTitle()+1)
    self.playCurrTrack()

def getTitle(self):
    return self.titleNum

def setTitle(self, number):
    self.titleNum = number
    if self.titleNum < 0:
        self.titleNum = len(self.playlist) + self.titleNum
    elif self.titleNum >= len(self.playlist):
        self.titleNum = len(self.playlist) - self.titleNum
    print("track %i of %i: %s" % (self.titleNum+1, len(self.playlist), self.playlist[self.titleNum]))
```

=====

This is called thus:

```
def main():
try:
  print "Ready.."
  global myplayer
  myplayer = AudioPlayer()
  myplayer.add_to_playlist(random_selector())
  myplayer.playCurrTrack()


  while True:
   time.sleep(1)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print "Shutdown requested...exiting"
except Exception:
    sys.exit(0)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I have a small method to mimic the Jukebox called random selector:

```
def random_selector():
  #removed R for Radio & V for playlists
  string.letters="ABCDEFGHJKLMNPQST"
  string.numbers="12345678"
  LET = random.choice(string.letters)
  NUM = random.choice(string.numbers)
  track_choice = m_path+LET+NUM
  return track_choice
```

This method is called via GPIO to mimic the jukebox selection:

```
def new_track_callback(channel):
  # call new track when button pressed
  global myplayer
  myplayer.add_to_playlist(random_selector())
  print ("New Track Added")
```

Edited to include the output, essentially I've added another print command in playTrack to make sure its actually getting fired OK, also print the track to ensure its got a value:

```
Track ended
Get Next Track
track 2 of 2: /mnt/usb/C4
trying to load new track...
trying to play track...
Entered playTrack
<vlc.Media object at 0x7649ef50>
```